# loop through numeric text files in bash and add numbers row wise

Tags: bash

I have a set of text files in a folder, like so:

```
a.txt
1
2
3
4
5

b.txt
1000
1001
1002
1003
1004
```

.. and so on (assume fixed number of rows, but unknown number of text files). What I am looking a results file which is a summation across all rows:

```
result.txt
1001
1003
1005
1007
1009
```

How do I go about achieving this in bash? without using Python etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Using awk

Try:

```
$ awk '{a[FNR]+=$0} END{for(i=1;i<=FNR;i++)print a[i]}' *.txt
1001
1003
1005
1007
1009
```

How it works:

- `a[FNR]+=$0`

  For every line read, we add the value of that line, `$0`, to partial sum, `a[FNR]`, where `a` is an array and `FNR` is the line number in the current file.
- `END{for(i=1;i<=FNR;i++)print a[i]}`

  After all the files have been read in, this prints out the sum for each line number.

#### Using paste and bc

```
$ paste -d+ *.txt | bc
1001
1003
1005
1007
1009
```

Comment: You nailed it down! Was also about to post the `paste` solution, but just realized you have it already :)

Comment: Thank you so much @John - I did not even think this was possible!